# can delete rows mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I need to delete the non-active member who is the 0 under the is_active column.

this is my query

```
DELETE FROM data 
WHERE 
    is_active in (0) 
;
```

No errors but it would not delete the members who are non-active.

Comment: What is wrong with `DELETE FROM data WHERE is_active = 0` ?

Comment: .. and even `DELETE FROM data WHERE NOT is_active;`.

Comment: It does not delete the row as well for some reason

Comment: *It does not delete the row* Error or "effected rows: 0"?

Comment: Like it just stay the same for the table

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM data WHERE NOT is_active;` selects rows?

Comment: well it works with SELECT * FROM data WHERE is_active = 1; @Akina 
But does it delete the rows?

Comment: Not possible, please add sample data as text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3dee3719793885905b62ce707da9d7c4

Comment: What is the datatype of is_active column?

Comment: the datatype is tinyint()

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data type for the `is_active` column. I suspect your column is text or a string data type in which case you could try:

`DELETE FROM data WHERE is_active = '0';`